# Escribir diccionario a CSV en Python 3, donde tanto llaves como valores sean filas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.7, diccionarios

Tengo dos diccionarios que quiero trasladar a un CSV, pero no quiero que las llaves (keys) se conviertan en columnas y los valores en filas, sino que ambas sean filas. Ambos diccionarios comparten llaves, pero los valores son diferentes

Estos son mis diccionarios:

```
diccionario = {"A": 1 , "B": 2, "C": 3} 
diccionario2 = {"A": 8, "B": 9, "C": 10}
```

La solución que intenté fue esta:

```
with open('diccionarios.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, diccionario.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(diccionario)
    if diccionario.keys() == diccionario2.keys():
        w.writerow(diccionario2)
```

Sin embargo el resultado que me regresa es este:

```
A     B     C  
1     2     3
8     9     10
```

Quería saber si hay una forma de lograr que se vea asi:

```
A 1 8
B 2 9
C 3 10
```

Y de ser posible agregar un nombre de columna propio, por ejemplo

```
LETRA NUMERO NUMERO2
A      1       8
B      2       9
C      3       10
```

Otra solución que había intentado era pd.melt (uso Pandas), pero la ausencia de una id_var me ha impedido poder abordar el problema desde este ángulo. 
Muchas gracias de antemano y saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si asumimos que ambos diccionarios tienen las mismas claves, es mucho más simple, con usar `dicc.items` sobre uno de los diccionarios y obtener luego el valor de la clave del segundo usando la clave del primero basta:

```
import csv


diccionario = {"A": 1 , "B": 2, "C": 3} 
diccionario2 = {"A": 8, "B": 9, "C": 10}

with open('diccionarios.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(("LETRA", "NUMERO", "NUMERO2"))
    for key, value in diccionario.items():
        writer.writerow((key, value, diccionario2[key]))
```

**`diccionarios.csv`**.

> ```
> LETRA,NUMERO,NUMERO2
> A,1,8
> B,2,9
> C,3,10
> ```

## Versión universal

Si no podemos asumir que tengamos siempre las mismas claves en los diccionarios y si queremos que funcione sin importar el número de diccionarios, la clave es `dict.get`, podemos hacer algo como:

```
import csv


diccionario1 = {"A": 1 , "B": 2, "C": 3} 
diccionario2 = {"A": 8, "C": 10}
diccionario3 = {"D": 13}

dics = [diccionario1, diccionario2, diccionario3]
with open('diccionarios.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    keys = {key: None for dict in dics for key in dict.keys()}.keys()
    headers = ("LETRA", *(f"NUMERO{i}" for i in range(1, len(dics) + 1)))
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for key in keys:
        writer.writerow((key, *(dict.get(key) for dict in dics)))
```

**`diccionarios.csv`**.

> ```
> LETRA,NUMERO1,NUMERO2,NUMERO3
> A,1,8,
> B,2,,
> C,3,10,
> D,,,13
> ```

---

> ```
> >>> import pandas as pd
> >>> pd.read_csv("diccionarios.csv")
>
>   LETRA  NUMERO1  NUMERO2  NUMERO3
> 0     A      1.0      8.0      NaN
> 1     B      2.0      NaN      NaN
> 2     C      3.0     10.0      NaN
> 3     D      NaN      NaN     13.0
> ```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Intenté ambas y funcionario perfectamente. Me quedo con la primera porque en mi caso todos los diccionarios siempre tendrán las mismas llaves.

Answer (score 2):

## Primera parte

Para determinar los valores de tu primer pregunta

> Quería saber si hay una forma de lograr que se vea asi:
>
> `A 1 8
>   B 2 9
>   C 3 10`

puedes usar el siguiente codigo

```
import csv
diccionario = {"A": 1 , "B": 2, "C": 3,"D":5} 
diccionario2 = {"A": 8, "B": 9, "C": 10,"E":6}
with open('diccionarios.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key,key2 in zip(diccionario.keys(),diccionario2.keys()):
        if(key == key2):
            f.write("%s,%s,%s\n"%(key,diccionario[key],diccionario2[key]))
        elif(key != key2):
            f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,diccionario[key]))
            f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key2,diccionario2[key2]))
```

## Segunda parte

Para el segundo caso puedes usar el siguiente codigo

```
import csv
diccionario = {"A": 1 , "B": 2, "C": 3,"D":5} 
diccionario2 = {"A": 8, "B": 9, "C": 10,"E":6}
with open('diccionarios.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=["LETRA", "NUMERO1","NUMERO2"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for key,key2 in zip(diccionario.keys(),diccionario2.keys()):
        if(key == key2):
            f.write("%s,%s,%s\n"%(key,diccionario[key],diccionario2[key]))
        elif(key != key2):
            f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,diccionario[key]))
            f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key2,diccionario2[key2]))
```

Comment: Intenté ambas y me funcionaron de maravilla. ¡Muchas gracias!